# Cannot change customer country

Tags: php, ajax, debugging

So here's the problem.

Backend Magento users who login at http://example.com/admin who are given a roll whose "resource access" is "All" are able to change any given customer's country.

However, if a backend user has a user roll whose "resource access" is set to "Custom" cannot change a customers country. When the Ajax request fails with a 403 error the user is redirected back to his dashboard. I have tried giving this user resource access = custom, and then checking off all possible options with no luck.

I'm at a loss for how to debug this thing, does any one know what's wrong? Or have ideas on where to start?
Thanks!